# Same web forms in two websites in same solution file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I had a website application project. During the course of time, different projects keep on added to the solution. Now there are more than 7 projects in the solution.

Now, I want to add another website project in the solution, in a way that it could re-use some of the forms of the existing website.

I want to add those web forms **as a link** to the newly added website project. Is that possible in my scenario?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not working as websites are deployed differently, what will happen when you release your projects?

Comment: @nuux I would like the forms to be deployed in the published folder for each of the two websites...

Comment: Two different websites under IIS web server, right?. Ok, of course, the solution I thought is use absolute url(not in visual studio) and change forms' design(masterpage) dynamically looking into the referrer, but then many questions arise - how the resources used by the forms are managed, how to manage security, logging ..etc. I think it'll get complicated requiring more effort than minimize.

Comment: you are right. much more complexity introduced...

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend doing this, you can add references to class libraries to use them in another projects but using web forms in another project in the same solution will not be the best scenario.

Comment: I won't recommend it either. But, this is the requirement. Same functionality is required in two websites' some of the forms, and re-writing the code every time, or least, copy pasting the files is not a good solution...

Comment: why don't you do a public code library and make it accessible from the whole solution so that you don't have to write the code or copy paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use file system hard links / junctions to make the same files/folders appear in two places. But that probably won't play well would source control, unless you can get it to ignore one of them.